# $T:P_4(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow P_4(\mathbb{R})$ such that $N(T) = P_1(\mathbb{R})$ and $R(T)=P_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

So, I'm asked to give an example of a linear map $T:P_4(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow P_4(\mathbb{R})$ such that $N(T) = P_1(\mathbb{R})$ and $R(T)=P_2(\mathbb{R})$.

As far as I understand, I'm trying to find a transformation that both takes $x\in N(T)=\{x\in P_4(\mathbb{R}):Tx=0\}$ such that all of them are in $P_1(\mathbb{R})$, while also transforming polynomials from $P_4(\mathbb{R})$ to all of $P_2(\mathbb{R})$, correct?

Can I use another vector space that $P_4(\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to?

Comment: Please don't answer until some discussion has been produced, if that's possible...

Comment: How can I construct this given arbitrary values of $n$; that is, should my professor change the subscripts for the criteria on the kernel and the image.

Comment: I suspect $f''$ is involved...

Comment: $P_n$ means polynomials of degree $n$ or $\leq n$?

Comment: Here it means polynomials in $P(\mathbb{R})$, the set of all polynomials, having degree less than or equal to $n$, yes...

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $T$ that sends the element $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e \in P_4(\mathbb{R})$ to $ax^2+bx+c \in P_4(\mathbb{R})$.  It remains to show that this map is linear and has the desired null set and range.

Comment: OP wanted to discuss it

Comment: @Mathematician OP means what?

Comment: Coffee_Table_2.0 How is $P_1(\mathbb{R})$ the null space? Isn't $P_0(\mathbb{R})$ the null space here?

Comment: I think the transformation here is $f''$...

Comment: @Mathematician Actually, I'm not sure. It seems it's the former case; that is, of degree $n$.